# Group by multiple columns and select the records with the maximum values of another column which is less than a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL question.  I have the following table:

```
 ID A   B   C  
 1  A1  B1  C1  
 2  A1  B1  C2  
 3  A2  B2  C3  
 4  A1  B1  C3  
 5  A2  B2  C2  
 6  A3  B1  C1  
 7  A1  B1  C4  
 8  A2  B1  C1
```

I want to select one row from each group where the 'A' and 'B' are the same.  For instance rows 1,2,4,and 7 form a group where A = 'A1' & B = 'B1'.  Within these groups I want the record with the greatest value in column 'C' that isn't greater than 'C3' so record #4 in the above group.

Here is the result set I'm looking for:

```
ID  A   B   C  
4   A1  B1  C3  
3   A2  B2  C3  
6   A3  B1  C1  
8   A2  B1  C1
```

Comment: That's a really bad question title... Also, StackOverflow is not about *I need code, give me code*. It's about *here's what I tried, and here's the issue I'm facing. Could you help me fixing it?*. So, **what have you tried?**

Comment: Could you post what you have already tried and why it's not giving the intended output ?

Comment: The actual query is much more complicated than this, with 3 joins and dozens of columns. That's the reason I didn't show what I already tried - I thought it was to confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CTE and a ranking function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, A,   B,   C,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY C DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
    WHERE C <= 'C3'
)
SELECT ID, A,   B,   C
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might give you what you want:

```
Select A, B, Max(C) as maxC
(
  Select *
  From SomeTable
  Where C <= 'C3'
) as nested
Group By A, B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_Number()
                 OVER (
                   PARTITION BY A, B
                   ORDER BY C DESC) AS RN
        FROM   #TEMP)A
WHERE  RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ID,A,
            B,C
  FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
            OVER(
              partition BY A, B
              ORDER BY id, c DESC)rn,
          *
   FROM   tabl1)p
 WHERE  rn IN( 1, 3 )
   AND id > 1
```